# 'search' is decorated with takes_context=True so it must have a first argument of 'context'. Django 2.1.5

Tags: python, django

I make search with `inclusion tag`, but this causes an error "*'search' is decorated with takes_context=True so it must have a first argument of 'context'*"

**inclusion_tag.py**

```
@register.inclusion_tag('post/search_tpl.html', takes_context=True)
def search(self, context, *args, **kwargs):
    request = context['request']
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    founded = Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query)|Q(body__icontains=query))
    return {'founded': founded}
```

This is not class and can do without 'self', but I getting error "Cannot use None as a query value". If I remove "self" - this causes an error "*Cannot use None as a query value*" (Traceback this editing is following)

If I replace "self" to second place - this causes en error "*'search' did not receive value(s) for the argument(s): 'self'*"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 156, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 154, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 214, in render
    _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/media/m0nte-cr1st0/43338d5a-aa90-411c-a6d7-96964c46e415/m0nte-cr1st0/programming/post/post/templatetags/all_comments.py", line 76, in search
    founded = Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query)|Q(body__icontains=query))
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 844, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 862, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1263, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1281, in _add_q
    current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1225, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1101, in build_lookup
    raise ValueError("Cannot use None as a query value")
ValueError: Cannot use None as a query value
[21/Jan/2019 09:37:00] "GET /post/profile/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 185464
```

**search_tpl.html**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none">
  <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="sbx-icon-search-13" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
    <path d="M26.804 29.01c-2.832 2.34-6.465 3.746-10.426 3.746C7.333 32.756 0 25.424 0 16.378 0 7.333 7.333 0 16.378 0c9.046 0 16.378 7.333 16.378 16.378 0 3.96-1.406 7.594-3.746 10.426l10.534 10.534c.607.607.61 1.59-.004 2.202-.61.61-1.597.61-2.202.004L26.804 29.01zm-10.426.627c7.323 0 13.26-5.936 13.26-13.26 0-7.32-5.937-13.257-13.26-13.257C9.056 3.12 3.12 9.056 3.12 16.378c0 7.323 5.936 13.26 13.258 13.26z"
    fill-rule="evenodd" />
  </symbol>
  <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="sbx-icon-clear-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <path d="M8.114 10L.944 2.83 0 1.885 1.886 0l.943.943L10 8.113l7.17-7.17.944-.943L20 1.886l-.943.943-7.17 7.17 7.17 7.17.943.944L18.114 20l-.943-.943-7.17-7.17-7.17 7.17-.944.943L0 18.114l.943-.943L8.113 10z" fill-rule="evenodd" />
  </symbol>
</svg>

<form novalidate="novalidate" onsubmit="return false;" class="searchbox sbx-google" action="{% url 'search_view' %}" method='GET'>
  <div role="search" class="sbx-google__wrapper">
    <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Поиск по сайту" autocomplete="off" required="required" class="sbx-google__input">
    <button type="submit" title="Нажми, чтобы найти" class="sbx-google__submit">
      <svg role="img" aria-label="Search">
        <use xlink:href="#sbx-icon-search-13"></use>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <button type="reset" title="Очисть" class="sbx-google__reset">
      <svg role="img" aria-label="Reset">
        <use xlink:href="#sbx-icon-clear-3"></use>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.querySelector('.searchbox [type="reset"]').addEventListener('click', function() {  this.parentNode.querySelector('input').focus();});
</script>
```

**base_generic.html**

```
...
{% load inclusion_tag %}
...
{% search %}
...
```

Comment: can you post the whole stacktrace please?

Comment: For first edition? Or second? This is not class and can do without 'self', but I getting error "Cannot use None as a query value"

Comment: what happens with `def search(context):`

Comment: Updated. This is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about like this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('post/search_tpl.html', takes_context=True)
def search(context):
    request = context['request']
    query = request.GET.get('q')  # removed self. That was causing the problem
    if not query:
        return {}
    founded = Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query)|Q(body__icontains=query))
    return {'founded': founded}
```

Comment: That means you are not getting any value in `request.GET.get('q')`. You need to hit the url like i.e. `http://localhost:8000/?q=abc`.

Comment: Also, I have updated my answer, if query is not found, returns an empty dictionary

Comment: sorry did not get that. Maybe you can put a debugger or write `print(request.GET)` in the code to see what is appearing.

Comment: I decided this in a different way. Writed `SearchView` with getting context, writed template `search.html` for shown result and writed form of search in `base_generic.html`